# Unifying color scale of different tiles in Google Earth Engine?

Tags: google-earth-engine, tiles, color

I found some other posts asked the similar questions but in different tools like ArcGIS, GDAL, QGIS etc. What I want to ask is how to do this in GEE.

Now I have removed the bad observation pixels (like clouds and scan-line corrector-off gaps in southern Florida. But I found every tile has its own unique color scale. Particularly for the tile Path:16 Row:43 (the one locates at the southwestern corner which covers Key West) has a significant difference with other tiles, which results in a big error when I calculating and filtering the indices.

Here I attached the code and screenshot for your reference.

```
//Choose country using GEE Feature Collection

var region = ee.Geometry.Polygon({
  coords: [[[-82.48, 26.93], [-79.91, 26.93], [-79.97, 25.68], 
            [-80.78, 24.75], [-81.21, 25.07]]],
  geodesic: false
});


var landsat8 = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_SR');

// Fmask classification values var FMASK_CLEAR_GROUND = 0; var FMASK_WATER = 2; var FMASK_CLOUD_SHADOW = 3; var FMASK_SNOW = 4; var FMASK_CLOUD = 5;

var non_mosaic = landsat8 .filterBounds(region) .filterDate('2017-01-01', '2017-12-31');

var getQABits = function(image, start, end, newName) {
    // Compute the bits we need to extract.
    var pattern = 0;
    for (var i = start; i <= end; i++) {
       pattern += Math.pow(2, i);
    }
    // Return a single band image of the extracted QA bits, giving the band
    // a new name.
    return image.select([0], [newName])
                  .bitwiseAnd(pattern)
                  .rightShift(start);
};

// A function to mask out cloudy pixels.
var cloud_shadows = function(image) {
  // Select the QA band.
  var QA = image.select(['pixel_qa']);
  // Get the internal_cloud_algorithm_flag bit.
  return getQABits(QA, 3,3, 'Cloud_shadows').eq(0);
  // Return an image masking out cloudy areas.
};

// A function to mask out cloudy pixels.
var clouds = function(image) {
  // Select the QA band.
  var QA = image.select(['pixel_qa']);
  // Get the internal_cloud_algorithm_flag bit.
  return getQABits(QA, 5,5, 'Cloud').eq(0);
  // Return an image masking out cloudy areas.
};

var maskClouds = function(image) {
  var cs = cloud_shadows(image);
  var c = clouds(image);
  image = image.updateMask(cs);
  return image.updateMask(c);
};

var mosaic_free = non_mosaic.map(maskClouds).median();

var visParams = {bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2'],min: [0,0,0],max: [2000, 2000, 2000]};

Map.addLayer(mosaic_free, visParams, 'Cloud free');
```

[image]